# Debugging symbols are enabled in the application in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, penetration-testing

How to disable the debugging symbols in Xamarin.iOS application.I get this bug from penetration testing team.The below step I have already did, but again I get the same error from the team.

iOS solution =>Option=>ios Debug=> Enable debugging (unchecked)

Please helps me on this , am stuck on this for a week.

Comment: After you have unchecked the `Enable debugging` option, can you try to `Delete bin and obj` folder and then `Clean and Rebuild your solution/project` to see if it works?

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT How to test does it works or not, am not much aware in VAPT.

Comment: I'm sorry that `Vulnerability Assessment and Penetration Testing`  is out of our scope.

Comment: @AlexandarMay-MSFT , okay Actually we are giving App center build for the testing . So in app center it won't take the bin and obj files.Is there any other solution for this. I am stuck on this for a week

Comment: If you are using `App Center`, you should reach out via [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/help#accessing-app-center-free-support).